# Obtaining automatically the Foursquare VenueId of many POIs

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, geolocation, mapkit, foursquare

In my iphone app, I've the latitude and longitude of hundred of places represented in a MapKit. Is there any automatic way of getting the 4sq venue ids of them using the api? I don't want to do that task manually.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no one-to-one mapping between annotations in the MapKit and foursquare venues. You would have to map these somehow yourself, whether amnually or by som fancy algorithm.

You should however be careful by mapping a "place" to a foursquare venue - how do you know it's the same just because it's within a few meters? How do you obtain these "places"?

You can see the Foursquare API documentation [here](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/) in case you decide to map these using some form of script or code.